# Best way to load X amount of previous messages on chatting app

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I'm making a chatting app and I'm wondering what the best way to load x (let's use 25 for an example) amount of previous messages were sent when ever the user requests. [the general structure looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GKfM.png)

I've attempted only two things before, the first one where I simply just have one div that contains all the messages, and when the user requests to view the previous messages, the entire chat is reloaded including 25 or so of the previous messages. This is somewhat messy and seems to be inefficient if one were to have hundreds or thousands of messages loaded in.

The second option I tried was creating a new div and then loading in the 25 previous messages into that div, but the problem is that I don't know how to properly place that div on top of the already loaded-in messages, and I don't even know if this possible, or would produce results that I'd like. (Example below, you don't have to understand everything, just the general idea):

```
newdiv = document.createElement('div');
loadPreviousDiv<?php echo $serverid ?> += 1;
newdiv.setAttribute("id", "loadPrevious" + loadPreviousDiv<?php echo $serverid ?>);
document.getElementById('serverchatarea<?php echo $serverid ?>').appendChild(newdiv);
```

So, what would be the best way to accomplish this? I know that php is not the best thing to use for a live chatting app, but it's something I'm stuck with at the moment. I also know that this is probably mostly a html/js question but it's possible that php could play a role in this as well.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/attacomsian.com/blog/javascript-insert-element-before%3famp might help you

Comment: Is the chat app based on Node.js? If yes you can maintain a `slice` of an array - choose the length and ensure the array always has the last n entries, This would be done within the node server code so no chance of interference by users.